# On Map Region Change in MapKit Android Sdk

Tags: android, mapkit

I am implementing a Map Kit based application in Android. I was very new to this sdk. My problem is I need to fire a method when the Map Region changed. Can you please guys let me know is it possible to fire a method when the region did Changed?

Thanks in Advance,
T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question already posted here:

[On Map Region Change in MapView Android Sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829170/on-map-region-change-in-mapview-android-sdk)